# Does a Quiz App belong in the Games category on Apptivate.ms

Tags: support, apptivate.ms

Which category does a Quiz App belong to:

- In a Knowledge category
- In a Games Category
- In a Work  Category

I have already submitted my app in the apptivate.ms contest. If I change the category then will it affect anything such as the comments and votes of my app?

Comment: Sounds like something you should be asking Microsoft since they're the ones curating the Windows Store, not us.

Comment: what about the other part of my question                         "Which category does a Quiz App belong to:
a Knowledge category, a Games Category or a Work Category"

Comment: Those are based on the Windows Store categories. Once you're able to categorize your app in the store, it shouldn't be a problem picking one for Apptivate.

Comment: Where does a quiz app generally belong to? which would be the most appropriate category?